# play sound from an analog microphone in Java

Tags: java, microphone

I wired an Raspberry pi to an ADC which is connected to an `!analog! microphone`. 
Is it actually possible to process the data of the ADC so I could pass it to a `javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine` or anything like this with java?

Comment: If you would pass input directly to an output it should work just fiine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily try this out, e.g. http://www.codejava.net/coding/capture-and-record-sound-into-wav-file-with-java-sound-api

Java capture api has a decent documentation (more than enough) at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html